# HTTP status 400 when trying to add web service reference to a project

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, soap

I am trying to add [this WCF service reference](https://api.onecallnow.com/WebService/3.1/soap.svc) to my Visual Studio 2012 C# project. When I try to load the service through the add service dialog, I get this error

> There was an error downloading
>   'https://api.onecallnow.com/WebService/3.1/soap.svc/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/$metadata'.
>   The request failed with HTTP status 400: Bad Request. Metadata
>   contains a reference that cannot be resolved:
>   'https://api.onecallnow.com/WebService/3.1/soap.svc'. Content Type
>   application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 was not supported by service
>   https://api.onecallnow.com/WebService/3.1/soap.svc.  The client and
>   service bindings may be mismatched. The remote server returned an
>   error: (415) Cannot process the message because the content type
>   'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type
>   'text/xml; charset=utf-8'.. If the service is defined in the current
>   solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference
>   again.

I've looked at other questions with this error, but almost all of them suggest changing something about the WCF service configuration, to which I don't have access.

Someone suggested that the last part of the message means that I am using a different version of SOAP than the service is using, but I don't see any options to change that in the Add Web Service dialog.

Can someone help me correctly add this service reference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you go the service in a browser, you will see the following:

[image]

The service owner has disabled metadata publishing, so you will not be able to add a service reference through the Add Service Reference dialog.

If the owner of the service can provide you with the WSDL and other metadata files, you can build a proxy using the [ServiceModel Meatadata Utility Tool (SvcUtil.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733%28v=vs.110%29.aspx); otherwise they may have alternative approaches you can use.

That of course, assumes that this service is intended for public consumption.

Comment: Yeah, it took me a long time to figure out that you can't consume the service without metadata publishing.